# "Real" testing of sms receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have a `SmsReceiver`which I would like to test for real on a device, however I'm not willing to send a bunch of real sms's to my device that stacks up my phone bills;-)

So I thought that I must be able to kick of an `intent` with action `RECEIVED_SMS`, sms data and all other stuff needed to send a sms. After a quick tour on google I ended up here: http://blog.dev001.net/post/14085892020/android-generate-incoming-sms-from-within-your-app. 
I took some ideas from this post and made my killer android app for creating and "sending" sms on the device for test purpose, and I must say that it worked like a charm, except that my receivers `onReceive` isn't invoked, the sent sms just goes directly to the inbox. I know that my receiver works, if I send a real sms to my device it triggers, and if I send an sms from DDMS to an emulator it also triggers, so that should be fine.

So is there any `permissions`, some `Intent.putExtras` or other stuff that I miss? Any tips is really helpful and if a could get this to work it would help me a lot in testing and developing of my application.

My receiver in manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
     <intent-filter android:priority="1000"> 
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/> 
     </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

Permissions in manifest(receiving application):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Permissions in manifest(sending application):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"/>
```

Should also mention that no errors are showing up in LogCat or in console.

Comment: No I'm using Jelly Bean(think API lvl.16), thanks anyway. Would be really nice if I could test my receiver "for real" this way

Comment: Thanks, I would really appreciate that! It's very annoying when it "should work" but doesn't;-)

Comment: Did you ever get this solved?

Answer (score 1):

**This is how my receiver looks like in the manifest :**

```
<receiver android:name="com.mike.broadcastexample.BroadcastReceiverClass" android:exported="true" > 
            <intent-filter android:priority="999" > 
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </receiver>
```

The only thing I am doing extra is that I have set the **android:priority to 999** and added **android:exported="true"**

These were the only permissions I used for the app:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

I was having the same problem with my application too and it was HTC ONE which has Android 4.3 but after making some changed to this receiver, its working absolutely perfect.

You can give it a try too.

Comment: Still no success in this, have now extended my receiver with exported='true' and set priority to 999 but still it fails.

Comment: Alright.. I had one question though..why this permission ?"<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"/>"

Comment: And does your receiver looks exactly the way I posted the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following receiver declaration also make sure that your **SMsReceiver** exists in main package or else provide complete path "****path***/SmsReceiver*" here path means the complete package path.

```
 <receiver
            android:name=".SmsReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="5822" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Also all permissions seems to be fine , just if your sending SMS too , just include

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that there are three possibilities here, each with their own use case and level of authenticity.

First, obviously, you could send real SMS messages to your phone. Consider getting a cheap prepaid SIM-card with a good SMS price deal if your current phone plan isn't adequate. Another option is to [use Skype to send SMS](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA3591/how-do-i-send-an-sms-from-skype), which could prove both cheaper and more convenient than using a real device.

Second, test on the emulator or via ADB on your real device. This is supposedly "the same" as receiving a real SMS as far as I know. The benefit is of course that it's free, and also quite handy as it allows you to manipulate the SMS parameters more easily than on a device.

Third, once you are satisfied with the above two testing levels, consider that an alternative to actually sending and receiving real `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcasts might be to break out most of your logic from `onReceive()` to another method, which you can then invoke manually.

*SmsBroadCastReceiver.java*

```
public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "SmsBroadcastReceiver";


    public class SmsMessageData{
        public String body;
        public String sender;
        public long timestamp;
    }


    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        SmsMessageData data = parseSmsMessage(intent.getExtras());
        handleSmsMessageData(context, data);
    }

    public void handleSmsMessageData(Context context, SmsMessageData data) {
        // Do what you want with the data, for example store it in your database
        // and show a notification. Note that data might be null!
    }


    private SmsMessageData parseSmsMessage(Bundle intentExtras) {
        if (intentExtras != null) {
            Object[] smsArray = (Object[]) intentExtras.get("pdus");

            if (smsArray != null) {
                String format = intentExtras.getString("format");
                StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder("");
                String sender = "";
                long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

                for (Object sms : smsArray) {
                    android.telephony.SmsMessage smsMessage = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M ? android.telephony.SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms, format) : android.telephony.SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms);
                    body.append(smsMessage.getMessageBody());
                    sender = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
                    timestamp = smsMessage.getTimestampMillis();
                }

                SmsMessageData result = new SmsMessageData();
                result.body = String.valueOf(body);
                result.sender = sender;
                result.timestamp = timestamp;
                return result;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

You can then easily simulate receiving a message by calling

```
new SmsBroadcastReceiver().handleSmsMessageData(this, data);
```

and passing any data that you need from within your application.

So, to recap, the first two testing levels deal with testing your basic SMS-parsing logic with varying degrees of authenticity, and the third level is a more abstract way of testing whatever your `BroadcastReceiver` actually does once it has parsed a received SMS.